# How to unlock a secured lockscreen

Tags: android, passwords, lockscreen

I would like to ask about the ability to unlock a secured lockscreen.

I'm able to get the lockscreen type ( pattern - password - pin ..etc ), and to unlock it, i was thinking about saving the pattern and unlock the lockscreen, example :

The lockscreen type is password, i popup a dialog to the user, and ask him to enter the lockscreen password, now, when it's time to unlock the device i use the password he entered, and unlock the lockscreen .

I'm able to save the password and make it secure, but i'm unable to enter that saved password to the lockscreen, also how to achieve that to pattern, or face? .

Comment: "i'm unable to enter that saved password to the lockscreen" -- this is by design. "i popup a dialog to the user, and ask him to enter the lockscreen password" -- you may wish to discuss your plans with qualified legal counsel. An attorney can advise you as to whether your planned app will be legal in your jurisdiction.

Comment: I live in Syria, so i don't think it's a problem lol, plus the app won't have any internet access permission, it's an offline app, that only unlock/lock the device at this moment, and won't send anything, or share any saved passwords.